# How do I dynamically change the gradient of a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a gradient that I want the user to be able to change dynamically. The div style is:

```
<div id="colourGradientDiv" style="background: <?php echo $colour_start; ?>; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  <?php echo $colour_start; ?> 0%, <?php echo $colour_end; ?> 100%); background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,<?php echo $colour_start; ?>), color-stop(100%,<?php echo $colour_end; ?>)); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  <?php echo $colour_start; ?> 0%,<?php echo $colour_end; ?> 100%); background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  <?php echo $colour_start; ?> 0%,<?php echo $colour_end; ?> 100%); background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  <?php echo $colour_start; ?> 0%,<?php echo $colour_end; ?> 100%); background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  <?php echo $colour_start; ?> 0%,<?php echo $colour_end; ?> 100%); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='<?php echo $colour_start; ?>', endColorstr='<?php echo $colour_end; ?>',GradientType=0 );">
```

I am using Ajax to change the colour with the following code:

```
$("#colourGradientDiv").css({"background" : colour_start,
 "background" : "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, "+colour_start+"), color-stop(100%, "+colour_end+"))",
 "background" : "-webkit-linear-gradient(top, "+colour_start+" 0%, "+colour_end+" 100%)",
 "background" : "-o-linear-gradient(top, "+colour_start+" 0%, "+colour_end+" 100%)"
 "background" : "-ms-linear-gradient(top, "+colour_start+" 0%, "+colour_end+" 100%)",
 "background" : "linear-gradient(to bottom, "+colour_start+" 0%, "+colour_end+" 100%)",
 "filter" : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='"+colour_start+"', endColorstr='"+colour_end+"',GradientType=0 )"
});
```

The above code doesn't chagne the div at all. However, if I just set the first "background" property then I change the whole colour of the div so I know that I'm addressing the div correctly and that the variable colour_start is correct.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: you can add a class instead of adding inline styles

Comment: How would I be able to adjust the colour values inside the class though? The colours need to be dynamic and picked by the visitor? Could I do that with a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do something like :

```
$('#block').css({
background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from($colour_start), to($colour_end))" 
});
```

And call this every time the client change the color of start or end.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would the webkit-gradient work on every browser?

Comment: Let say most current ones but you can add the other background property to the function with no problem !

Comment: But isn't that what I'm doing in my original post? Adding the every background property in order to cope with every browser and it's not working? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I mean you must call `$('#block').css({ ...` for **each** background property.